# In JavaScript, recursively build a dictionary / nested object from a set of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, reduce

I feel like a bit of a dummy, but I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

I have a set of arrays, and I need to use them to build a JSON-ish object.

e.g.

```
[a]
[a, b]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
[e]
[e, f]
[e, f, g]
```

becomes

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {}
      d: {}
    }
  }
  e: {
    f: {
      g: {}
    }
  }
}
```

And so on.

What I would like to do is:

1. Instantiate an empty object, Dictionary
2. Take an arbitrary array of length n
3. Iterate over the array, such that at array position i, if Dictionary doesn't have a property at Dictionary[Array[0]]...[Array[i]], I define that property as Array[i]: {}

The problem I have is looking at the arbitrary path to the property in question. I don't know how to build a multi-level path to the property name I'm looking for. i.e., when i === 0,

```
var check = Array[i];
typeof Dictionary[check] === 'undefined';
```

We're going to get expected behavior. But it's obviously going to build the whole array as a flat set of object properties (instead of a nested dictionary).

I don't then have a way to add the next step to the *check* variable --

```
...
check = check[Array[i+1];

check = Dictionary[check][Array[i+1]]
```

and further permutations aren't going to work.

I'm sure I'm missing something dumb here, but I got stuck on it and would appreciate insight if anyone had it.

And, to note, if at all possible I need to do this only using jQuery or lodash, if it's not achievable reasonably in plain JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

```js
lst = [
    ['a'],
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'd'],
    ['e'],
    ['e', 'f'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g']
];


tree = {};
lst.forEach(function(item) {
    item.reduce(function(node, chr) {
        return node[chr] || (node[chr] = {});
    }, tree);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you. I was sure it was something dumb I was blanking on.

Comment: To note, for some reason IE10 doesn't implement .reduce() for Arrays. Was able to make it work with Lodash though.

Comment: @Matt: that's strange, given that it works fine in IE9.

Comment: Agreed, by the various definition sites it didn't look like there should have been an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have a more succinct answer, but I'd already written it...

```js
var arrs = [
    ['a'],
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'd'],
    ['e'],
    ['e', 'f'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j']
];

var dictionary = {};

arrs.forEach(function (item) {
    addArray(dictionary, item);
});

document.getElementById("output").innerText = JSON.stringify(dictionary, null, 3);

function addArray(dic, arr) {
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        dic = addNode(dic, item);
    });
    return dic;
}

function addNode(node, item) {
    return node[item] || (node[item] = {});
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Georg's answer is shorter but your verbosity was helpful, thanks for posting it.